# Bootstrap Tooltips not disappearing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

[image]

I have bootstrap tooltips that appear when the user hovers over them. There are times when these tooltips do not disappear. They will stay on the screen like this for the duration of the application. They will remain when I change to a new screen of the application. I figure it might have something to do with the javascript for creating the tooltips so here is the function that handles the tooltips.

```
function addTooltips() {
    var myDefaultAllowList = bootstrap.Tooltip.Default.allowList
    myDefaultAllowList.table = []
    myDefaultAllowList.tr = []
    myDefaultAllowList.th = []
    myDefaultAllowList.thead = []
    myDefaultAllowList.tbody = []
    myDefaultAllowList.td = []
    myDefaultAllowList.a = []

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').on('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    });
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).tooltip('hide')
    });
    $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
        trigger: 'hover'
    })

    $('#lst_art_adm').on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });

    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))

    const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
    const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
}
```

Could any of this help explain why these tooltips stay on the screen. It doesn't always happen. It seems random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use AJAX to load new content it is best to hide all tooltips and popovers. I use this function:

```js
function hidePopper()
{
  $(".tooltip").remove();
  $(".popover").remove();
}
```

Use this function before you process the AJAX call. That way they will always disappear when they need to.

The reason that tooltips do not disappear can be that you replaced the HTML code they are based upon by new HTML code.

As you know you also need to activate tooltips and popovers. I use this function for that:

```js
function activatePopper()
{
  let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(\'[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]\'));
  let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
  });
  let popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(\'[data-bs-toggle="popover"]\'));
  let popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
  });
}
```

I always use this function after an AJAX call has completed. Any tooltips or popovers in the new code will work after calling this function.

In other words, I don't handle individual tooltips or popovers, I handle them as a group.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I'm using Blazor so I believe adding this to OnAfterRenderAsync might handle it. Hopefully adding this will prevent it. It's hard to test so I won't know for a while.

Comment: @DaveK Note that the `hidePopper()` I posted here requires JQuery, whereas the `activatePopper()` does not. You can, of course, make a hidePopper()` function in plain javascript.

Comment: I have more information to share on this so I will update the original question.

Comment: @DaveK: Please don't post replies in my answer, it's simply not the place for it. I did read your remark however, and I've updated my answer. Try this new `hidePopper()` function and see if that will work.

Comment: Oh! Rats! I'm sorry. That is not where i was supposed to put that!

Comment: and... that might be working. I was thinking of this but you definitely beat me to it.